# How to make a custom torchvision transform?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have a function that changes image pixels with 20% chance, but not sure how to make it work in transforms.Compose([]). Please help!

```
def random_t(img):
    im = Image.open(img)
    pixelMap = im.load()
    pixelMap_list = []

    for i in range(im.size[0]):
        for j in range(im.size[1]):
            randNum = random.uniform(0, 1)
            if randNum < 0.2:  # 20% chance of pixel change
                pixelMap[i, j] = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
            pixelMap_list.append(pixelMap[i, j])
        else:
            pixelMap[i, j] = pixelMap[i, j]

    return im
```

I think it should have a format like this.. this is from pytorch library.

```
class custom_augmentation(object):
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p # it should be the probability of random pixel

    def __call__(self, img):
        return None # Not sure how to make random_t in here

    def __repr__(self):
        return "custom augmentation"
```

## fixed code:

```
class custom_augmentation(object):
    def __init__(self, p=0.5):
        self.p = p

    def __call__(self, img):
        pixelMap = img.load()
        for i in range(img.size[0]):
            for j in range(img.size[1]):
                if torch.rand(1) < self.p:
                    pixelMap[i, j] = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
                else:
                    pixelMap[i, j] = pixelMap[i, j]

        return img # Not sure how to make random_t in here

    def __repr__(self):
        return "custom augmentation"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do your operations on `img` and then return it. For a good example of how to create custom transforms just check out how the normal torchvision transforms are created like over here:

This is the github where torchvision.transforms like `transforms.Resize()`, `transforms.ToTensor()`, `transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip()` have their code. Look at these transforms like `RandomHorizontalFlip()` to see how to introduce a probability that a transform will happen etc.

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Callable object. e.g.

```
class Task_transform_mi(Callable):
    def __init__(self, ways, samples):
        self.ways = ways
        self.samples = samples

    def __call__(self, dataset):
        return get_remaining_transforms_mi(dataset, self.ways, self.samples)
```

In my experience this is done to avoid lambda functions, since those nasty little buggars break the dataloader when the `num_workers > 0`. This happens because afaik the multiprocessing code tries to pickle the dataset and lambda's can't be pickled (unless you use dill perhaps).

So to avoid this you can do:

1. Create function name for your lambda. This works fine if you don't need to remember variable parameters for your function. If that is the case then my suggestion is to use a sateful callable like option 2 or 3.
2. You can create brand new Callable object as the example above.
3. You can create a method in an object that has a state and then pass a reference/pointer to that method. Creating a Callable is likely nicer.

An example for 2:

```
def mi_img_int_to_img_float(x) -> float:
    return x / 255.0
```

An example for 3:

```
class FullOmniglotUU(Dataset):
    """

    [[Source]]()

    **Description**

    This class provides an interface to the Omniglot dataset.

    The Omniglot dataset was introduced by Lake et al., 2015.
    Omniglot consists of 1623 character classes from 50 different alphabets, each containing 20 samples.
    While the original dataset is separated in background and evaluation sets,
    this class concatenates both sets and leaves to the user the choice of classes splitting
    as was done in Ravi and Larochelle, 2017.
    The background and evaluation splits are available in the `torchvision` package.

    **References**

    1. Lake et al. 2015. “Human-Level Concept Learning through Probabilistic Program Induction.” Science.
    2. Ravi and Larochelle. 2017. “Optimization as a Model for Few-Shot Learning.” ICLR.

    **Arguments**

    * **root** (str) - Path to download the data.
    * **transform** (Transform, *optional*, default=None) - Input pre-processing.
    * **target_transform** (Transform, *optional*, default=None) - Target pre-processing.
    * **download** (bool, *optional*, default=False) - Whether to download the dataset.

    **Example**
    ~~~python
    omniglot = l2l.vision.datasets.FullOmniglot(root='./data',
                                                transform=transforms.Compose([
                                                    transforms.Resize(28, interpolation=LANCZOS),
                                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                    lambda x: 1.0 - x,
                                                ]),
                                                download=True)
    omniglot = l2l.data.MetaDataset(omniglot)
    ~~~

    """

    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, target_transform=None, download=False):
        self.root = os.path.expanduser(root)
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

        # Set up both the background and eval dataset
        omni_background = Omniglot(self.root, background=True, download=download)
        self.len_omni_background_characters = len(omni_background._characters)
        # Eval labels also start from 0.
        # It's important to add 964 to label values in eval so they don't overwrite background dataset.
        omni_evaluation = Omniglot(self.root,
                                   background=False,
                                   download=download,
                                   target_transform=self._target_transform)

        self.dataset = ConcatDataset((omni_background, omni_evaluation))
        self._bookkeeping_path = os.path.join(self.root, 'omniglot-bookkeeping.pkl')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        image, character_class = self.dataset[item]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        if self.target_transform:
            character_class = self.target_transform(character_class)

        return image, character_class

    def _target_transform(self, x):
        return x + self.len_omni_background_characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use only `__init__`,`__call__` functions for custom transforms. See the custom transforms named `CenterCrop` and `RandomCrop` classes redefined in [preprocess.py](https://github.com/jangsoopark/AConvNet-pytorch/blob/main/src/data/preprocess.py), which are composed using `torchvision.transforms.Compose()` along with along with the already existed transform `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()` in `load_dataset` function in [train.py](https://github.com/jangsoopark/AConvNet-pytorch/blob/main/src/train.py).

I ran the code. It is working perfectly, which makes sure the correctness of defining *custom transform*